# Open data sets and commercial usage

Tags: machine-learning, licensing

If you train a machine learning model from publicly available (Open) data sets such as COCO or VOC (which have there own respective licenses), can you use that model for commercial purposes?

Comment: maybe a better question for open source se

Comment: can you elaborate on COCO/VOC? what are they?

Comment: http://cocodataset.org/#home and http://host.robots.ox.ac.uk/pascal/VOC/ are probably what he was referring to. https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/13360/publicly-aviailable-data-sets-training-and-commerical-usage is also the same question.