# Publicly aviailable data sets, training and commerical usage

Tags: machine-learning, licensing

If you train a machine learning model from publicly available (Open) data sets such as COCO or VOC (which have there own respective licenses concerning commercial usage), can you use that model for commercial purposes regardless?

Comment: this was already migrated here from datascience.se

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because.
its not off-topic but i can't flag as a duplicate because the other question doesn't have an answer. but its clearly the same question, migrated from a different se domain. https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/13359/open-data-sets-and-commercial-usage

Comment: http://cocodataset.org/#home and http://host.robots.ox.ac.uk/pascal/VOC/ are probably what he was referring to.